# Subsetting data frames in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and learning about subsetting. I have a table and I'm trying to get the size of a subset of the table.  My issue is that when I try two different ways I get two different answers.  For a table "dat" where I'm trying to select all rows where RMS is 5 and BDS is 2:

```
dim(dat[(dat$RMS==5) & (dat$BDS==2),])
```

gives me a different answer than

```
dim(subset(dat,(dat$RMS==5) & (dat$BDS==2)))
```

The second one is correct, could someone explain why these are different and why the first one is giving me the wrong answer?

Thanks

Comment: no need to use dat$ inside subset `dim(subset(dat, RMS==5 & BDS==2))` but I think even with , you should get the same result.

Comment: You would help us to help by providing some of your data, for example with `dput( head( dat, 20 ) )` or so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason must be in different treatment of NA values by these two methods. If you remove rows with NA from the data frame you should get the same results:

```
dat_clean = na.omit(dat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.....

```
> x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
> y = c(4,4,5,5,6,6)
> 
> X = data.frame(x,y)
> 
> dim(X[X$x==1 & X$y==4,])
  [1] 2 2
> 
> (X[X$x==1 & X$y==4,])
   x y
 1 1 4
 2 1 4

> dim(subset(X,(X$x==1) & (X$y==4)))
  [1] 2 2
> subset(X,(X$x==1) & (X$y==4))
  x y
1 1 4
2 1 4
```