# How to form a subset from a set of data in R?

Tags: r

Let x be the vector for the height of fathers

```
x <- c(180.3, 177.4, etc)
```

and y be the height of the corresponding sons

```
y <- c(179.5, 178.5, etc)
```

I now want to create a subset of fathers whose height is within 2.5cm of `x=182` with the corresponding sons. How do I do this?

Comment: Did you try anything? Where exactly did you get suck? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Including parts like "etc" isn't very useful since that's not reproducible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I filter a range of numbers in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107901/how-do-i-filter-a-range-of-numbers-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical vector to subset the 'x'

```
i1 <- x >= (182 - 2.5) & x < (182 + 2.5)
x1 <- x[i1]
y1 <- y[i1]
```